# numpy.loadtxt: load a range of columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `.csv` file with both string and integer - containing columns. I need to use `numpy.loadtxt` method to import the matrix formed from the specified columns. How can I do that? Right now I am trying to do the following:

```
data = np.loadtxt(open(path_to_data, "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1, usecols=[1:])
```

Basically trying to read all columns but first, but it is giving an error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Because such syntax is not allowed: `usecols=[1:]`

Comment: Please put some dummy sample data and use pandas for reading in data files

Comment: "I need to use `numpy.loadtxt`" - no, you don't. There is also the more powerful [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

Comment: @heltonbiker, `genfromtxt` expects the same sort of `usecols` input.

Comment: `[1:]` is allowed only in an indexing context.  It is not a `range` expression.  Use `np.arange(1,10)` or how ever many columns you need.  Basically `usecols` needs a list of column numbers.  There's no `all-but-the-first` shortcut.

Comment: Both `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` load with default float dtyype.  But `genfromtxt` puts `nan` where it can't convert the string to float, while `loadtxt` raises an error.  So you could load all columns, and do the `data[:,1:]` extraction after.

Comment: Yeah, this is just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax error:

```
In [153]: [1:]
  File "<ipython-input-153-4bac19319341>", line 1
    [1:]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's not specific to `loadtxt`.

Use

```
data = np.loadtxt(open(path_to_data, "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1, usecols=np.arange(1,n))
```

where `n` is the total number of columns.

```
usecols : int or sequence, optional
    Which columns to read, with 0 being the first. For example,
    ``usecols = (1,4,5)`` will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns.
    The default, None, results in all columns being read.
```

---

If you don't know `n`, and don't want to use a preliminary file read to determine it, `genfromtxt` might be easier.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(..., delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

should load all columns, putting `nan` where it can't convert the string into float.  If those `nan` are all in the first column, then

```
data = data[:,1:]
```

should give you all but the first column.

`genfromtxt` is a little more forgiving when it comes to converting strings to floats.

Comment: I know, but how to get this `n`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking `numpy.loadtxt()` to select columns, simply load them all and then slice the resulting array to remove the 1st column:

`data = np.loadtxt(open(path_to_data, "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)[:,1:]`

Then you don't need to know the value of `n` i.e. the number of columns and everything is on one line.

If you have a problem with converting strings to floats, you can then convert the dtype

e.g.

`data = data.astype('float64')`